# How do I deal with processes which continuously open/close ports and increasingly consume memory?

Tags: windows, memory, netstat

According to [file.net](http://www.file.net/process/nvtray.exe.html), nvtray.exe is some process for or from my video card.  When I look at the Netstat part of XAMPP, it shows nvtray.exe continuously opening and closing ports, increment the port number up, as seen in this picture:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5ie6tHd.png]

There's also a TmProxy.exe that has similar behavior.

Other processes have similar behavior, for example Chrome, but that seems more expected while I'm actually using Chrome.  nvtray.exe just sits in the background slowly doing this odd port behavior and consuming and increasing amount of ram.

Should I just kill nvtray.exe each time I see this happening and not worry about it?  Is there some particular reason nvtray.exe is doing this?